# Codeception with Webdriver - Clicking button with same name/value/type

Tags: php, css, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I'm trying to find out how I can use `$I->click` with codeception for a button that shares the same name/value/type as another button on the same page.  Examples are:

`<input class="submit_btn uppercase" type="submit" name="go" value="/GO/"> // button I want to click`

AND

`<input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="/GO/" name="go"> // button I don't want to click`

What syntax should I use to delineate between the two?  I've tried many different things including using the CSS locator after the button name like:

`$I->click('go', '.uppercase');  // 2nd item is CSS locator`

I've also tried:

`$I->click('go', '.submit_btn uppercase');  // 2nd item is CSS locator`

Comment: Can you try this:  $I->click('go', '.submit_btn.uppercase');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I believe you should find a nearest parent tag that has id defined. I'll assume that there is a parent tag that has id="formId"
Here is the code to click that element by CSS selector:

```
$I->click('#formId > input.submit_btn.uppercase');
```

There is another way that you could click this element by xpath:

```
$I->click('//input[@class="submit_btn uppercase"]');
```

Comment: The parent form does not have an id tag.  Some of this website was designed rather poorly.  However, the xpath locator does work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with codeception, but if it has full CSS selector support (ambiguous to me after a quick look at their docs) you can look at using a `:not(s)` [selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/).

If that's the case, you should be able to use something like:

```
$I->click('go', '.submit_btn:not(.uppercase)');
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to grab the class="submit_btn uppercase", not avoid that button.  This line of code causes parse error :(

Comment: True enough. Not sure how I inverted that in my head. Others have already suggested what I would follow up with, now.